# Overriding a view.py file in an external Django package

Tags: django, pip, package, overriding

I am working on a Django project and had to install a package with pip: 'authemail'. I want to override the view.py file and the serializers.py in this package. So I can customize the code without touching the package. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**My solution for now:**
I have copied the whole package in my application as an app. Django always tries this path for its imports. I removed the package from the requirements and make the changes in my newly added app. This is of course the last resort but for me the best route. Because when in the future the package will support my features I can easily switch back to using a package.